# Displaying location name from organizations lookup table in case list/case detalis

Tags: commcare

I referenced locations from my application's organization structure using a multiple choice lookup table and then saved the location as a case property. Now, I want to display the location name in my case list/case details.

By default (Plain format), the location_id field shows up in the case list/case details. Is there a way to display the name of the location in the case list/case details without manually mapping each location ID to its respective name (as you would with the ID Mapping format)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to save both the location_id and the location name to the case after your multiple choice question.  You can find the expression to get the location name from the location_id here:
https://confluence.dimagi.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38276915

Then, just display the location name in the case list rather than location_id.